# Geometry of edges created after using osm2pgsql

Tags: pgrouting, osm2pgsql

I used osm2pgsql to convert osm data to postgresql. Now I have a table with edges and they have geometry like multilinestring. I am not sure what is meant be geometry of an edge. An edge is supposed to be a line between two points/nodes(start and end). How does the geometry thing come in? Can anyone please elaborate? And I want to know if routing functions like pgRouting actually use this geometry when calculating/displaying the shortest route?

Comment: A beginners guide to pgrouting: http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/

Answer (score 2):

An edge contains a source and target, which describes your route-able network. For Dijkstra algorithm this is sufficient. 
A-Star and  Shooting Star algorithm have a heuristic component and make use of the geometry of source and target (x1,y1 and x2,y2). Source and target coordinates are pre-calculated for better performance.

The geometry (ie. multilinestring) is necessary for example to render the route, or to extract source and target points. It is not necessary for the shortest path algorithm.

Comment: That's what I am asking how the geometry is used while rendering the route. I have the geometry but how am I supposed to use it while displaying the route

Comment: Well, you didn't ask this. But how you render the route depends on what software you use for rendering. pgRouting only returns you an SQL result set. You can take a look at the workshop and see how you can return the SQL result as GeoJSON and render it as vector layer in OpenLayers.

Comment: This is the workshop link: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/

Comment: Actually, I don't want to use openlayers. Is there any way to return the results in gpx format. I mean how can I convert the multilinestring so that it can be represented in gpx format

Comment: GPX doesn't know linestrings. And you can't directly use the SQL output but need to parse the geometry and create a GPX track segment for each linestring: http://www.topografix.com/gpx/1/1/#type_trksegType

Comment: Yes that is what I want to know. How can I parse the linestring and convert it to GPX. I can see that the geom_way is a multilinestring with values like 0105000020E6100000010000000102000000050000004B4C61EF8F5F57C004C4C9A255794640A90E5E607B5F57C0C7269E584C7946403F1C2444795F57C0E06EA4C74A7946401C1E673F775F57C0C9F08E4248794640499B4FC2715F57C0977CA2A135794640. How can I actually create a track segment out of it.

Comment: ST_AsText(the_geom) gives you a readable format (WKT) of your geometry. You then need to parse the result set to extract the points.

Comment: dkasti, I tried that. However it  is still the same.